# Access private members of a class instantiated using interface

Tags: c++, class, interface, friend

I have a class derived from an interface and a friend class of the derived class. I want to access the members of derived class which is instantiated as interface. It looks like this:

Interface:

```
class AInterface
{
public:
   virtual ~AInterface() = default;
   virtual void set(int a) = 0;
};
```

Derived class A with friend class B:

```
class B;
class A : public AInterface
{
public:
   ~A() override {}
   void set(int a) override
   {
      mem = a;
   }
private:
   friend class B;

   int mem = 0;
};
```

class B:

```
class B
{
public:
   B() 
   {
     a = new A();
     a->set(3);
   }

   int get_a()
   {
      // Access mem since it's a friend class
      return a->mem;
   }

private:
    AInterface *a;
}
```

main:

```
int main()
{
    B *b = new B();
    std::cout << b->get_a() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program does not compile saying AInterface has no member named 'mem'.
Do I need getter functions in the interface and implement it in A to achieve this or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Hint: does it work if you make it `public`?

Comment: @juanchopanza It will work but I want to keep it private and follow the pricinples.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @juanchopanza tried it now. Doesn't work

Comment: Right. So it has nothing to do with `private` or `friend`. Now try making a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, you need getter functions in the interface and implement it in A. The function must be virtual.

Comment: @kwadhwa look to my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class AInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;
    int getMem() { return mem; }
    virtual void set(int a) = 0;
protected:
    int mem = 0;
};

class A : public AInterface
{
public:
    ~A() override {}
    void set(int a) override
    {
        mem = a;
    }


};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
         a = new A{};
        a->set(3);
    }

    int get_a()
    {
        // Access mem since it's a friend class
        return a->getMem();
    }

private:
    AInterface *a;
};
int main()
{
    B *b = new B();
    std::cout << b->get_a() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

1. Method which is override by child and is pure, should be virtual.
2. If each class (child) `Interface`, variable `int mem` should be protected in interface.
   Now works fine, like you want.
3. Add getter `getMem()`

Version with `friend`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class AInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;
    virtual void set(int a) = 0;
protected:
    friend class B;
    int mem = 0;
};

class A : public AInterface
{
public:
    ~A() override {}
    void set(int a) override
    {
        mem = a;
    }


};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
         a = new A{};
        a->set(3);
    }

    int get_a()
    {
        // Access mem since it's a friend class
        return a->mem;
    }

private:
    AInterface *a;
};
int main()
{
    B *b = new B();
    std::cout << b->get_a() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is using `friend` not correct here? By using `friend` the OP retains encapsulation while only exposing it's internals to a very select few. By adding an _accessor_ member function now exposes it to the entire world.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious okey, you've right, always each developer say "You never use `friend", but I never think about that like special access point

Answer (score 0):

In your class B.

```
class B
{
  //...
   int get_a()
   {
      return a->mem;   // but a is a AInterface*  !!!
   }

private:
    AInterface *a;     // That's not an A*, but an AInterface*
};
```

You have 2 options.

1. use `dynamic_cast<>`

   ```
    int B::get_a()
    {
        A* p = dynamic_cast<A*>(a);
        if (p)
          return p->mem;  
        // a is not an A*, it's another AInterface*-type object !!!  
                                      // What should you do?
        throw something_or_other();   // throw?
        return -1;                    // return an error code?
      }
      // or maybe add..  so you can check for errors before calling get_a()
      A* B::get_A_ptr() const 
      { 
         return dynamic_cast<A*>(a); 
      }
   ```

dynamic_cast works fine, but can slow down your app if you need to make frequent reads of `a->mem`.

2. Store `a` in an `A*`, which is probably what you meant to do from the start...

   ```
   class B
   {
     // ...
   private:
     A* a;    // now a->A::mem is visible.
   };
   ```

Since you explicitly call `new A` in B's constructor, I think option 2 is better for your case.